# Error in using Map scheme type in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, typeerror, mongoose-schema, mongoose-models

I had defined my mongoose schema like this

```
export const DIDSchema: mongoose.Schema = new Schema({
    socialMediaHandles: {
        type: Map,
        of: String
      }
});
```

but when I try to compile the code, I am getting error like
**TypeError**: Undefined type `Map` at `socialMediaHandles`
  Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.

Comment: What version of Mongoose are you running

Comment: Any news on this ? I have the same problem